# how to update the caption of a post on instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to update the caption of a post on instagram by JavaScript.

I learned how to create a new post from the guide below, but I didn't know how to update the captions of a post that has already been posted.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Comment: Doesn't look like any kind of update operation other than enabling / disabling comments is actually possible, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media#update

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's only able enabling / disabling comments. I understand